# Starting up Reactive Engine throws error "java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.romix.akka.serialization.kryo.KryoSerializer"

Tags: installation, akka, upgrade

When starting the layline.io Reactive Engine, it throws the error

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.romix.akka.serialization.kryo.KryoSerializer
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:com.romix.akka.serialization.kryo.KryoSerializer
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
```

There is no further information on why this error is thrown or how to remedy it.

How can this be fixed?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This problem is likely due to the fact that you are upgrading layline.io from a previous version. The installer does not overwrite the configuration directory if this already exists from a previous installation.

Take a look at the `application.conf` file which probably has a reference to the missing class.

The easiest thing to fix this is to

1. Uninstall the previous version
2. Delete the configuration directory (`.layline`)

```sh
# Windows
C:\Users\<username>\.layline

# MacOS
 /Users/<username>/.layline/
 
 # Linux
 /usr/local/layline/config/
```

3. Reinstall layline.io

Make sure to make a backup of your configuration settings to reuse later.